# Getting date/time from Mt. Gox's "now" value using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mtgox

I connected to `https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox` using socket.io (https://socketio.mtgox.com/socket.io/socket.io.js), and it returned an object that looks like this:

```
{ 
    exchange: 'mtgox',
    buy: 106.54693,
    sell: 106.99653,
    last: 106.54693,
    vol: 57734.68992687,
    now: 1371584138359638,
    _id: 51c0b68ab3067d631c000002
}
```

I'm looking for the time and date of the event. There is `now:`, which appears to be Timestamp, but `new Date(1371584138359638);` returns `Wed Oct 09 45433 05:59:19 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

Year 45,433 suggests I'm wrong.

I checked out https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming#Depth, and `now:` appears in the object, but is not described in the description below.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Call it at 1 second intervals and see how the value changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in microseconds, and JavaScript uses milliseconds.  Divide by 1000.

```
var dt = new Date(1371584138359638 / 1000);
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but that date is Jun 18 of this year, is that right?

Comment: @Vap0r - That's what it looks like, yes.

Comment: @Vap0r - Yeah, I copied this from older data I have stored in my database.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Unix epoch timestamp in microseconds (0 is 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC)